# Rotating model in openGL 2 in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, rotation, 360-panorama

I'm working with OpenGl on iOS and Android, what I'm trying to do is draw a model, a sphere, set the camera/eye coords inside the sphere, set a texture and enable panning and zoom to achieve a 360 degree effect, I just made for Android using OpenGl 1.0, but I was having a lot of problems in iOS, so I made it using OpenGl 2.0, everything is set and working, but I'm having a problem with the panning, in order to rotate the Model View matrix, I'm applying the rotate transformation, it works but if I change any axis rotation, it messes up the other two axis, At the end if I apply a rotation in both axis, X and Y, the sphere rotates like if some kind of transformation has been don in the Z axis, the texture ends upside-down or being displayed in diagonal, I'm doing the exact same transformations in Android and I don't have any problem there, anybody has some experience with this issue? Any suggestion? clue? code? article? I think that when I apply the first transformation the coords in the space just change and the next transformation is not being applied properly.

Here's my iOS code :

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLKMatrixStackPush(_obStack);

    GLKMatrixStackRotate(_obStack,
                         GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_obAngleX),
                         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    GLKMatrixStackRotate(_obStack,
                         GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_obAngleY),
                         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    GLKMatrixStackScale(_obStack,
                        _obScaleFactor,
                        _obScaleFactor,
                        _obScaleFactor);

    self.obEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrixStackGetMatrix4(_obStack);

    // Prepare effect
    [self.obEffect prepareToDraw];

    // Draw Model
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, panoramaVertices);

    GLKMatrixStackPop(_obStack);
    self.obEffect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrixStackGetMatrix4(_obStack);
}
```

This is my Android code :

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arGl) {
        arGl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        arGl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        arGl.glPushMatrix();

        arGl.glRotatef(obAngleY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        arGl.glRotatef(obAngleX, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     
        arGl.glScalef(obScaleFactor, obScaleFactor, obScaleFactor);

        if (obModel != null) {
            obModel.draw(arGl);
        }
        arGl.glPopMatrix();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying over and over again with several implementations, every single time with no success, at the end, I went back and implemented the OpenGL 1.0 version for iOS and under this scenario, whenever the matrix is being rotated, the axis aren't, so this was my solution, implement the OpenGL 1.0 version.